# inserting node at specified point into xml using visual basic & xpath(or other)

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have an XML document similar to the structure below. Using visual basic how can I insert nodes at the different levels depending on Id & Name.

does Xpath allow me to insert new nodes or does it only allow the modification of existing nodes?
so for example if I wanted to add `<BuildingPart Id="B012" Name="Bedroom" Type="Room"/>` after "B011 Bathroom" how can this be achieved?

```
<Buildings>
    <BuildingPart Id="B001" Name="House">
        <BuildingPart Id="B002" Name="Level 1" Type="Level">
            <BuildingPart Id="B003" Name="Kitchen" Type="Room"/>
            <BuildingPart Id="B004" Name="Bedroom" Type="Room"/>
            <BuildingPart Id="B005" Name="Lounge" Type="Room"/>
            <BuildingPart Id="B006" Name="Bathroom" Type="Room"/>
        </BuildingPart>
        <BuildingPart Id="B007" Name="Level 2" Type="Level">
            <BuildingPart Id="B008" Name="Bedroom" Type="Room"/>
            <BuildingPart Id="B009" Name="Bedroom" Type="Room"/>
            <BuildingPart Id="B010" Name="Study" Type="Room"/>
            <BuildingPart Id="B011" Name="Bathroom" Type="Room"/>
        </BuildingPart>
    </BuildingPart>
</Buildings>
```

Thanks.

Comment: XPath doesn't allow you to insert new nodes *or* modify existing nodes. Instead, you could use something like XSLT to transform your input XML to a modified output, including additional elements.

Comment: Im using Xpath just to navigate to corresponding node then with that node do something.
wouldnt the appendChild method of the XmlDocumnet class work once I have navigated to node?

Comment: Yes, if you're using DOM / XmlDocument, that would be one way to do it. (You would have to create the child element first, using CreateElement, as SysDragon showed.) You would then need to output the modified DOM to a file presumably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Dim doc As Xml.XmlDocument
Dim myNode As Xml.XmlNode

doc.Load(sFileName)

myNode = doc.GetElementById("B001").Clone()
myNode.Attributes("Id").Value = "B012"
myNode.Attributes("Name").Value = "Bedroom"
myNode.Attributes("Type").Value = "Room"

doc.GetElementById("B007").AppendChild(myNode)
```

**EDIT:**

To create the node from the begging without cloning simply:

```
myNode = doc.CreateElement("BuildingPart")

myNode.SetAttribute("Id", "B012")
myNode.SetAttribute("Name", "Bedroom")
myNode.SetAttribute("Type", "Room")
```

**EDIT:**

As seen in [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx) you need to specify always which element is the ID for an element in order to use `GetElementById`:

> The DOM implementation must have information which defines which attributes are of type ID. Although attributes of type ID can be defined in either XSD schemas or DTDs, this version of the product only supports those defined in DTDs. Attributes with the name "ID" are not of type ID unless so defined in the DTD. Implementations where it is unknown whether the attributes are of type ID are expected to return Nothing.

In order to do that, you can add at the beggining of your xml this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE Buildings[
<!ELEMENT BuildingPart ANY>
<!ATTLIST BuildingPart Id ID #REQUIRED>]>
```

If you cannot change the file, you have to loop through the elements and check the id from the attributte:

```
For Each elem As XmlElement In doc.GetElementsByTagName("BuildingPart")
    If elem.GetAttribute("Id").Equals("B007") Then
        elem.AppendChild(myNode)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I get a Nullreferenceexception was unhandled error on 
line "myNode = doc.GetElementById("B001").Clone()".

would I be correct in saying that its null because it cant find anything with specified Id? even though Ids are exactly as written above

Comment: Of course. Instead of cloning a node, try to create a new one from the begging. I edit my asnwer.

Comment: using your editted code, there is no function title "SetAttribute" for the myNode element.

also, I still need a way to insert the new node into the document because the GetElementById always throws a nullreference exception

Comment: If it throws a `NullReferenceException` is because the id doesnt exists. And if you use the second edited part, create the var `myNode` as `Xml.XmlElement` istead of Node

Comment: Something is juts not right,
my code is as follows
       
    'imports system.xml'
    'Dim doc As New XmlDocument'
    'Dim myNode As XmlElement'

    'doc.Load("c:\project xml\Project.xml")'

    'myNode = doc.CreateElement("BuildingPart")'

    'myNode.SetAttribute("Id", "B012")'
    'myNode.SetAttribute("Name", "Bedroom")'
    'myNode.SetAttribute("Type", "Room")'

    'doc.GetElementById("B007").AppendChild(myNode)'

and the XML is exactly as written above with the addition of
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' at the top

Comment: Ok, I realized the problem. As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.xml.xmldocument.getelementbyid.aspx), you need to define the ID in order to retrieve it with `GetElementById`. I edit my answer

Comment: Problem solved! :)
the clone function from original code works too.

Thank you very much.